# What is the use of .scope() in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, scope

What is the use of .scope() in AngularJS? I have seen some code examples using this but I am not quite sure what the use is, and I have been unable to find an answer in SO posts and in AngularJS documentation. For example:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("MainWrap")).scope();
```

Is this somehow similar to use of $digest or $apply?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)?

Comment: Yes, I just wasn't clear where it says: "To retrieve the associated scope in console..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of what I use it for every day:

- Open Console in dev tools.
- Right-click an element in your page that is managed by AngularJS, select `inspect element` option
- Now write in console:  `angular.element($0).scope()`

You just got a scope of said element as that element sees it. You can go up through the parent, manage its content (don't forget to $apply() afterward to test the change, otherwise, it won't bind) or do similar things you can in console with any JS object.

There are more uses for it for sure internally, but this one I find really helpful when debugging. So in relation to `$apply()` it is and is not linked to it, depending what you use it for.

Comment: So is .scope() meant to be used solely for debugging? Seems like that's the case given your uses as well as the documentation.

Comment: It could be used internally, I never looked over entire AngularJS code. You are free to search for it.